# Comparing two arrays isn`t working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check for the same numbers in "checked" and "numbers". There are six numbers in each array and equal once shuld be outputed in the array "same".
There are 0 elements in "same" even if there are the same numbers in the array. The code to compare the two arrays is right ( I tested it before) but here it wont work.
Please help
Thanks

```
function getNumbers(){

    var boxes = document.forms[0];
    var checked = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        if (boxes[i].checked) {
            checked[checked.length] = boxes[i].value;
            }
        }
    if(checked.length != 6){alert("Pick 6");}
    else{
        document.getElementById("Ausgabe2").innerHTML = "You picked: "+checked;

    var numbers = [];
    var randomnumber;

    while(numbers.length < 6){
            randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*49)
            if(numbers.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
            numbers[numbers.length] = randomnumber;
    }

    numbers.sort(sortNumber);

    document.getElementById("Ausgabe").innerHTML = numbers;
```

Here the comparing part begins. If I declare 'numbers' and 'checked' here again it works but I dont`t want to do this.

```
    var same = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (numbers.indexOf(checked[i]) != -1) {
                same.push(checked[i]);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("Ausgabe3").innerHTML = "You`ve got " + same.length + " right: " + same;    
    }
}

function sortNumber(a,b) {
        return a - b;
    }
```

Comment: `same = checked.filter(num => numbers.indexOf(num) !== -1)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because each time you enter a value in array `same` you enter it at a fixed index which is `undefined` (or 0, depends on how you've initialized the array)

```js
// These declarations are only for this demo
var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var checked = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var same = [];

// Start of the snippet
// Replace the below part in your code
var len = (numbers.length < checked.legth) ? numbers.length : checked.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (numbers.includes(checked[i])) {
    same.push(checked[i]); // This line is where your code had a error
  }
}
// End of snippet

console.log('same array:');
console.log(same);
```

**EDIT:**

You are understood JS array wrong. Youv'e used the following loop multiple times in the updated snippet in your question

```
for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) { // Iterate i from 0 till box.length
  if (boxes[i].checked) {
    checked[checked.length] = boxes[i].value; // For each value of i, the value of check.length is the same. So every time this condition is executed, you simply overwrite the value.
  }
}
```

Try to update your function wit the one below, I've updated few logical error's...

```
function getNumbers() {
  var boxes = document.forms[0];
  var checked = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].checked) {
      checked.push(boxes[i].value); // Updated here
    }
  }
  if (checked.length != 6) {
    alert("Pick 6");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Ausgabe2").innerHTML = "You picked: " + checked;
    var numbers = [];
    var randomnumber;
    while (numbers.length < 6) {
      randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 49)
      if (numbers.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
      numbers.push(randomnumber); // Updated here
    }
    numbers.sort(sortNumber);
    document.getElementById("Ausgabe").innerHTML = numbers;
    var same = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      if (numbers.indexOf(checked[i]) != -1) {
        same.push(checked[i]);
      }
    }

    document.getElementById("Ausgabe3").innerHTML = "You`
    ve got " + same.length + "
    right: " + same;    
  }
}
```

Comment: But stil it wont work unless i delare numbers and checked again. I added the whole code to the question so maybe you could check it out and tell me whats wrong about it

Comment: @Jack, udpated, try with the new snippet for the function

Comment: Still doesn't work, also the arrays are totally fine when I output them in 'Ausgabe1' and 'Ausgabe2' it there are 6 numbers so it doesn't overwrite the values.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for ?

```js
"use strict"

var numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11];
var checked = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var same = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < checked.length; j++) {
    if (numbers[i] === checked[j]) {
      same.push(numbers[i]);
    }
  } 
}

alert(same);
```

Comment: I don´t know I tried your code but it still didn`t work

Comment: There has to be somethink else wrong in my code but thanks for the effort

Comment: Yes your script is totally fine but  it sudently wont work in my script unles i declare numbers and checked right before again. I added the whole code to the question so maybe you  can help me some more after you `ve seen it.

Comment: Since you have declared your own numbers, checked and same variables so you just need to skip my variable declaration part and utilize my loop to check for same numbers between 2 arrays. You can print numbers and checked array right before loop for testing

Comment: If it doesn't work then there must be something wrong with your numbers or checked array. Log them with console.log() and see whether they are what you expected them to be